# dynamicly added input fields not in the post

Tags: jquery, post, http-headers

i dynamicly add some input field when pressing a button. but when i post the form the post values of the dynamicly added inputs are not set

```
$('.addslidebutton').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('<div class="edit-slide"><div class="input "><label for="imageurl-new-'+i+'">Afbeeldings url</label><input name="imageurl-new-'+i+'" value="" class="" type="text" id="imageurl-new-'+i+'"></div><div class="input "><label for="linkurl-new-'+i+'">Link url</label><input value="" class="" type="text" id="linkurl-new-'+i+'" name="linkurl-new-'+i+'"></div><div class="input "><label for="tekst-new-'+i+'">tekst</label><input value="" class="" type="text" id="tekst-new-'+i+'" name="tekst-new-'+i+'"></div></div>').insertBefore('.addslidebutton');
});
```

And the output html:

```
<div class="edit-slide">
   <div class="input "><label for="imageurl-new-1">Afbeeldings url</label><input name="imageurl-new-1" value="" class="elfinderselect" type="text" id="imageurl-new-1"></div>
   <div class="input "><label for="linkurl-new-1">Link url</label><input value="" class="" type="text" id="linkurl-new-1" name="linkurl-new-1"></div>
   <div class="input "><label for="tekst-new-1">tekst</label><input value="" class="" type="text" id="tekst-new-1" name="tekst-new-1"></div>
</div>
```

thanks for reading!

Comment: Post the relevant html as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first u must to do is make your code is readable for easly to development like this one

```
$('.addslidebutton').click(function(){
  var i = $(".edit-slide").length+1;
  $('<div class="edit-slide">\
    <div class="input ">\
      <label for="imageurl-new-'+i+'">Afbeeldings url</label>\
      <input name="imageurl-new[]" value="" class="" type="text" id="imageurl-new-'+i+'">\
    </div>\
    <div class="input ">\
      <label for="linkurl-new-'+i+'">Link url</label>\
      <input value="" class="" type="text" id="linkurl-new-'+i+'" name="linkurl-new[]">\
    </div>
    <div class="input ">\
      <label for="tekst-new-'+i+'">tekst</label>\
      <input value="" class="" type="text" id="tekst-new-'+i+'" name="tekst-new[]">\
    </div>\
   </div>').insertBefore('.addslidebutton')
});
```

Comment: Thank yu, i knew that you cant have a string in javascript acros multiple lines but i didn't now you can escape the newline characters